# MVC4 Foreign Key property is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, one-to-many

I have an Expenses and Categories tables. I have seeded the tables with few entries, but when pulled from DB the Category property is null. I would expect it to be automatically populated with entries from Category table. What am I missing?

**Model:**

```
public class Expense
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select some category!")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.CategoryId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Category.Description //NullReferenceException here
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: Expenses
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Expenses.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you have a virtual property for the Category in expense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try marking the Category property as `virtual`. Navigation properties need to be virtual to support the lazy loading if it is not eager loaded.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Out of curiosity how would I eagerly load this?

Comment: db.Expenses.Include(i => i.Category).ToList()